# Problems when solving $E(X\mid Y)$

Tags: conditional-expectation

If we know $X\sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$, $Y\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda_p)$:

When solving $E(X\mid Y)$, based on the law of iterated expectations, $E(X) = E(E(X\mid Y)) =\lambda$. And we know that $E(\lambda) = \lambda$, so can we just say that $E(X\mid Y)=\lambda$ ? But this answer is wrong I suppose.

Comment: $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable. We know that it has mean $\lambda$ -- this does **not** imply that it is equal to the constant $\lambda$, e.g. $X$ is a random variable that also has mean $\lambda$, but is not a constant.

Comment: In general, there's not a huge amount we can say without knowing how $X$ and $Y$ depend on each other. If they were independent, then $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=\mathbb E[X]=\lambda$, but this need not be true if $X$ and $Y$ depend on each other.

Answer (score 1):

It is not  possible in general to compute $E(X\mid Y)$ without any information on the dependence between $X$ and $Y$.

- If $X$ is independent of $Y$, then indeed, $E(X\mid Y)=\lambda$.
- If $\lambda>\lambda_p$ and $X=Y+Z$, where $Z$ is independent of $Y$ and has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda-\lambda_p$, then $E(X\mid Y)=Y+\lambda-\lambda_p$.